# Calculating ADX indicator with pandas DF / Smoothing average issues

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average, algorithmic-trading

I've been having issues calculating ADX indicator with pandas DF in Python. Been racking my brains the past few days regarding what is going wrong. My thinking is something to do with smoothing average maybe? the last couple of lines from the results are: The ADX for the last row '2021-07-03' should be around 33.

```
i.   date.      open.     high.     low.      close.              +DI.      -DM EMa.       -DI.         DX.          ADX.   
396 2021-06-30  35894.90  36088.87  34013.34  35036.58      ...   0.629251  -132.284380  -4.690877    1.309852   5.418229
397 2021-07-01  35048.78  35048.78  32720.03  33506.98      ...  -4.476247    57.794871   2.098175    2.764602   5.479026
398 2021-07-02  33502.26  33971.12  32698.40  33796.99      ...  -9.798669    52.972888   2.071717    1.536231   5.483165
399 2021-07-03  33831.62  34807.59  33322.38  34632.63      ...  -4.374875   -37.287497  -1.544599    0.478130   5.475540
```

My code below:

````
def adx_calc(df):

    for current in range(1, len(df.index)):
        previous = current - 1
        #True Range:
        tr = max((df.loc[current,'high'] - df.loc[current,'low']), (df.loc[current,'high'] - df.loc[previous,'close']), abs((df.loc[previous, 'close'] - df.loc[current,'low'])))
        df.loc[current, 'TR'] = tr
        df['ATR'] = df['TR'].ewm(span = 14).mean()
        # DM's:
        df.loc[current, '+DM'] = df.loc[current, 'high'] - df.loc[previous, 'high']
        df.loc[current, '-DM'] = df.loc[previous, 'low'] - df.loc[current, 'low']
        # + DI:
        df['+DM_EMA'] = pd.DataFrame.ewm(df['+DM'], span = adx_time_period).mean()
        df.loc[current, '+DI'] = ((df.loc[current, '+DM_EMA'] / df.loc[current, 'ATR']) * 100)
        # - DI:
        df['-DM_EMA'] = pd.DataFrame.ewm(df['-DM'], span = adx_time_period).mean()
        df.loc[current, '-DI'] = ((df.loc[current, '-DM_EMA'] / df.loc[current, 'ATR']) * 100)
        # # DX:
        df.loc[current, 'DX'] = (abs((df.loc[current, '+DI'] - df.loc[current, '-DI'])) / abs((df.loc[current, '+DI'] + df.loc[current, '-DI'])))
        # # ADX:
        df['ADX'] = df['DX'].rolling(window=14).mean()```
````

Comment: The problem is due to the use of a for loop. You compute the rolling average once in each iteration. When using pandas, try to avoid using for loops at all, the above computations should be able to be done easily without it. (For example, the `+DM` column can be done with `df['+DM'] = df['high'].diff()`.

Comment: oh okay! But I am calculating the ADX for many different times. As I want to calculate historical ADX data based upon past price action. Meaning I want an ADX value for each row of data.

Comment: That's fine, your current code for the ADX column will actually already give you that. Try moving it outside the for loop (just change the indentation on the `df['ADX'] = df['DX'].rolling(window=14).mean()` line to run it after the for loop is complete and check the result).

Comment: After de-denting it so it's outside the for loop, I still get the same results

Comment: You probably need to remove the for loop enteirly since you are mixing functions like `ewm` that works on the whole dataframe with `loc` and `current` computations. I guess that that is the issue but it's hard to know without an [mcve]. You could check if the `DX` column is correct or not as a next debugging step at least.